# Router Overload? Small office keeps dropping downloads

Tags: router, performance

We have a small office with 25-30 devices connected to the network. Most of the devices are working constantly.

ISSUE: cant download/upload through Ethernet, website load times are slow, cant have more than 2 people on wi-fi, downloads from wi-fi work but not Ethernet.

We have a set up of.

```
          ------> Network Drive

Modem---->Router 

          ------> Switch -----> Ethernet
```

Our Router is DLINK 835. We also have a switch DGS-1024D both are new because of the issue(we thought either router or network switch died)

My thought is that its the router - there might be just too many connections in the office and its not fast enough to handle the load and we need to get a new Enterprise level router.

I also looked at the log of the router. It keeps posing the same lines in the log. I have no idea what they mean.

```
Jan 18 20:50:40      info     using nameserver 64.59.144.18#53
Jan 18 20:50:40      info     using nameserver 64.59.144.19#53
Jan 18 20:50:40      info     reading /etc/resolv.conf
Jan 18 20:50:24      info     using nameserver 64.59.144.18#53
Jan 18 20:50:24      info     using nameserver 64.59.144.19#53
Jan 18 20:50:24      info     reading /etc/resolv.conf
Jan 18 20:50:17      info     using nameserver 64.59.144.18#53
Jan 18 20:50:17      info     using nameserver 64.59.144.19#53
Jan 18 20:50:17      info     reading /etc/resolv.conf
Jan 18 20:50:09      info     using nameserver 64.59.144.18#53
Jan 18 20:50:09      info     using nameserver 64.59.144.19#53
Jan 18 20:50:09      info     reading /etc/resolv.conf
Jan 18 20:50:05      info     using nameserver 64.59.144.18#53
Jan 18 20:50:05      info     using nameserver 64.59.144.19#53
```

Do you guys have any ideas? Suggestions for gear? Suggestions for temporary fix?

Comment: It's weird that manufacturers will list the capacities of the MAC address table and packet buffer memory for Ethernet switches, but specs for wireless router units (which incorporate a switch) typically do not mention such capacities.  It's almost like they are too embarrassed to reveal these capacities.  Normally a manufacturer will tout every common & unique feature and numerical capacity if they think it's better than their competition's products or want to out-spec the competition in RFP bids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this it? http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833127390

Looks like the majority including yourself have experienced poor performance. Other things to consider..

Is your modem a straight modem or modem/router combo? Double NAT's unfortunately work and will wreak havoc on your connection speed. WIth that said,

a SMB with 20+ users really requires something a little more robust than a soho router. Ive used Cisco's RV series routers for similar setups with great success.

Comment: yes thats the one. I dont think its router`s fault - its not broken or anything, it just cant handle the load.

we basically looking for something bigger and stronger. Talked to Cisco Agent and he advised Cisco 1921 router

Comment: do you have any recommendations on the router model from Cisco?

Comment: PS: The Modem is not a Moder+Router combo

Comment: Do you have a budget? You'll be dropping a thousand bucks on a 1921 series when you could probably get by with much less. 

http://www.neweggbusiness.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833150182&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleBiz&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleBiz-_-pla-_-NA-_-NA&gclid=CPrniKGK67ICFQjZQgodV2wAXw
 

Ive used this guy with great success. Dual WAN, Gigabit ethernet and support for 50 VPN clients.

Comment: So our network guy came by and told us that those logs that I posted mean that the DNS servers of ISP went down and thats why our internet was acting up - not because of our router.

Thanks for replies! I'll definitely look into that router for next upgrade project.